# Excel Formula =If(min),true, false

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, min

What formula do I need to label data based on two criteria, one of which is the minimum?

I am trying to label each row of data with a "Y" or "N".  In the example below, I am trying to find the object (row) where the minimum price (criteria 1) for each shelf (criteria 2) can be found.

[image: Example Data]

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `MINIFS`:

```
=IF(C2=MINIFS(C:C,B:B,B2),"Y","N")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks much! Double "ifs" worked like a charm. All set.